# Configuring BIND for Ubuntu Web Server

Tags: nginx, bind, postfix-mta, pointers

I am looking for some assistance configuring BIND to host a DNS server on my web server.

I recently acquired a dedicated server running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I already have Nginx, PHP-FPM, MariaDB installed and working perfectly. My knowledge of postfix & dovecot are slim, so I followed this guide: [A Mailserver on Ubuntu 14.04: Postfix, Dovecot, MySQL](https://www.exratione.com/2014/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1404-postfix-dovecot-mysql/). The good news is that I've got mail coming in and going out as expected, but have come across another issue, which is some ISP and providers are denying the mail since there is no PTR records used.

So, I'm assuming I need to install and configure BIND to set up DNS and to set up a PTR record so that my mail will reach its destinations. I've tried Google with some tutorials but none of them seem clear for my purpose.

Installing a control panel, or one of those all-in-one scripts is out of the question since I already have the web server configured. Another issue is that some of them don't work with Nginx or use a different configuration of PHP. Plus, I want to learn how to do this on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to install bind. Who ever has reverse DNS authority for your IP block will typically create a reverse name for you. Just request a reverse pointer record with the mail domain name for your IP.